# How to know the folder paths to code bits assembled with includes?

Tags: php, html, google-developers-console, google-developer-tools

The problem:
An "index.php" is built using three pieces of code: "header", "content" & "footer", when I use "view page source", I'll see only the fully assembled index.php code, not to what file part belongs the header, content or footer and what is the path of the inspected element.

The question:
 Is there some way to trace to what file and source path the inspected element is from using some feature of google dev tools or any other method?

I'm trying to edit a wordpress theme and it is split into so many parts that finding one specific line of code to fix the property that I want seems as hard as looking for a needle in the haystack.

I've tried to download the whole project locally and go through files one-by-one on the visual studio code file browser but this still seems so inefficient.

I'm trying to find to what file this line belongs so i can add to it an aria-label attribute:

`<a class="next page-numbers" href="https://blog.fdsm.edu.br/page/2/" data-wpel-link="internal" data-slimstat="5"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>`

the original source code belongs to this blog:
https://blog.fdsm.edu.br/

Comment: There is no way to figure that out on the client side (browser). All the assembling of code from various PHP files is done on the server. The client has no idea where the code came from.

Comment: and if I have access to the server side, would there be a way that isn't manually looking each file that composes the whole index of the example @MER?

Comment: If I have access to the source files, I generally do a `grep` from the command line. Such as:`grep -ri 'data-wpel-link'`

Comment: @MER I couldn't make it work but thanks anyway! :/